# Question on the differentiability of the solution mapping in the obstacle problem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, calculus-of-variations

I'm looking for a reference for the following. Take the obstacle problem:
$$\int_\Omega \nabla u \nabla (v-u) \leq \int_\Omega f(v-u)$$
for a function $u \in K:=\{v \in H^1_0(\Omega) : v \geq \varphi\}$ for a sufficiently nice given function $\varphi$, and holding for all test functions $v \in K$. Say $\Omega$ is a bounded smooth domain.

Denote $u=\sigma(f)$ as the solution map.

I read, some time ago, that depending on the nature of the coincidence set $\{u = \varphi\}$ and the obstacle $\varphi$, the solution map $\sigma$ can be Frechet or directionally differentiable or not differentiable at all (but I may be misremembering some aspects of this). Unfortunately I can't find a reference to these issues. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest starting with the seminal work of Mignot [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123676900173) where it is proven that the solution mapping is only directionally differentiable (provided you're capable of reading mathematics in French). If you are looking for a bigger picture, it might be worthwile to check out more modern papers which cite this one.

Comment: @Hannes I just checked the citations.. unfortunately nothing good. I'm familiar with the paper, but I think we can expect a bit more on the differentiability given sufficient conditions on the data. Incidentally, do you know any references for differentiability of the obstacle to solution mapping?

Comment: Maybe the introduction [here](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/130925827) helps some more? But I'm not really an expert in this field myself, sorry - I just happened to look through Mignot's paper a few days ago.